# Delete a sharepoint 2010 document library using stsadm command?

Tags: sharepoint, scripting, sharepoint-2010, stsadm

I am deploying a sharepoint 2010 custom document library template as a solution file and activating it to my site. When i am deleting the solution and deactivating the feature i also want to delete the libraries that were created from this template with all its contents. I have an uninstaller.bat file that performs the deactivation, i want to include the library removal script with the uninstaller. Is it possible to remove the libraries through stsasdm command?

Comment: There were trouble triggering the feature deactivation event from command line, i ended up writing a .exe that will just delete the libraries. I called this exe from the bat file and passed the site url as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Forcedeletelist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262609%28office.12%29.aspx), but you will need to know the URLs of the libraries you want to delete. [Note](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/11/delete-list-forget-about-forcedeletelist/), despite the name, this command will not delete the list if [AllowDeletion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.allowdeletion.aspx) is set to false.

Two things to consider:

1. In SharePoint 2010, stsadm has been [deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx) in favor of PowerShell.
2. To me, it would make more sense to perform this operation in the [FeatureDeactivating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featuredeactivating.aspx) method of a Feature Receiver instead of in a script.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a Feature Receiver http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469501.aspx that runs when the Feature is deactivated that will take care of the deletes for you.

Comment: I would replace could with should :)